# "Add Controller" / "Add View" in a hybrid MVC/WebForms ASP.NET application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

I have an existing WebForms project to which I'm adding MVC pages. I created an MVC project and copied the project type guids.

It works fine, but I can't get Visual Studio to display the "Add Controller" or "Add View" wizards on my controllers and views directories (they're not `/Controllers` and `/Views`, they're in `/Foo/Controllers` and `/Foo/Views`).

Is it possible to enable the wizards?

Comment: Probably and good luck, but I've always found that those are practically useless as views and controllers aren't much different at all than the regular aspx page and class.

Comment: @Will, if you add this as an answer I'd accept it - I also realized that I'm served just as well by code snippets

Comment: Is Foo a simple directory or Area?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've given up on this. Instead, I have some basic Resharper snippets. Too bad this isn't configurable.

Comment: Can you please tell me what snippets you're talking about here? Because scaffolding still won't work now would it?

Comment: @RobertKoritnik nothing fancy, just snippets that let me put the controller/view name and have the viewmodel name etc. derived based on my convention, e.g. `LoginView` -> `LoginViewModel`.

Comment: Still no solution? I've added some bounty to your question.

Answer (score 11):

For MVC 3, ProjectTypeGuids should look like the following:

```
<ProjectTypeGuids>{E53F8FEA-EAE0-44A6-8774-FFD645390401};{349c5851-65df-11da-9384-00065b846f21};{fae04ec0-301f-11d3-bf4b-00c04f79efbc}</ProjectTypeGuids>
```

(See [Upgrading an ASP.NET MVC 2 Project to ASP.NET MVC 3](http://www.asp.net/learn/whitepapers/mvc3-release-notes#0.1__Toc274034214))

Comment: -1: @orip told that he already changed the GUIDs. Guids are not a problem here. His question is: **How to make those context menus appear on different folders and not directly `Controller` and `Views`**.

Answer (score 6):

To get full designer support for hybrid projects you need to add MVC "project type" to  in the project file.

Open your project file and replace **ProjectTypeGuids** tag with

```
<ProjectTypeGuids>{F85E285D-A4E0-4152-9332-AB1D724D3325};{349c5851-65df-11da-9384-00065b846f21};{fae04ec0-301f-11d3-bf4b-00c04f79efbc}</ProjectTypeGuids>
```

After that you will see new context menus ("Add View", "Add Area", "Add Controller", etc) in your "old" ASP.NET project

Works for both MVC and MVC 2.

Comment: -1: OP already added those GUIDs you're referring to. His question is how to put those wizards on folders ie. `Foo\Controllers` and `Foo\Views` and not to those couple that are in the app root...

Answer (score 5):

For MVC 4:

```
<ProjectTypeGuids>{E3E379DF-F4C6-4180-9B81-6769533ABE47};{349c5851-65df-11da-9384-00065b846f21};{fae04ec0-301f-11d3-bf4b-00c04f79efbc}</ProjectTypeGuids>
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is the guid for MVC3 :

```
{E53F8FEA-EAE0-44A6-8774-FFD645390401};
```

unload your project, open csproj file and add the GUID to the begining of  tag. no extra spaces nor line breaks, then reload the project. Like this

```
<ProjectTypeGuids>{E53F8FEA-EAE0-44A6-8774-FFD645390401};{349c5851-65df-11da-9384-00065b846f21};{fae04ec0-301f-11d3-bf4b-00c04f79efbc}</ProjectTypeGuids>
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could enable them, but why bother? Those wizards are available just two clicks away: right click on the folder, click on Add - New item, then select "MVC View Page" or "MVC Controller Page". They are not in the contextual menu, but they are still quite near... :)

Comment: (1) I couldn't make the templates appear in "Add -> New Item" in this project [I don't know why], and (2) the "MVC View Page" template under "Add -> New Item" doesn't let me choose a statically-typed view model like the wizard does.

Comment: @orip: although it does choose the customized templates of controllers (if you put them in the `CodeTemplates` folder) it doesn't really help too much with views especially if you do use those scaffolded ones...

Answer (score 1):

This issue is resolved. I have a hybrid project and I had the same problem. Could not able to see "Add View/Add Controller" in the context menu. It is now resolved. Please see the following link [Context menu to Add Controller/View missing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10540198/context-menu-to-add-controller-view-missing)