# Add controller/view on other folders

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010

> ***Initial sidenote**: I'm working on a hybrid WebForms+MVC application that started as a WebForms application hence I've added project GUIDs that converted it to MVC. This means that I'm getting context menus directly on `Controllers` and `Views` folder in application root. That works.*

I was wondering whether it's possible to convince Visual Studio (and Asp.net MVC tooling) to add *Add controller...* and *Add View...* context menu items to other folders not just those default ones that are on the project root?

The reason is that I'm working on an Asp.net WebForms application that is now a hybrid with MVC. And since it already has quite a few folders in root I would rather separate the new MVC part and contain it altogether within `mvc` folder, so all MVC related files would be inside that particular folder.

But right clicking on `mvc\Controllers` doesn't give me the wizard, nor does the `mvc\Views`... Also navigation from controller code to views isn't working...

**Is there any way to customize this in Visual Studio?** Do Asp.net MVC tools for VS have some sort of configuration file where this can be configured? Or in registry maybe?

Comment: Have you checked this question: [“Add Controller” / “Add View” in a hybrid MVC/WebForms ASP.NET application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1600426/add-controller-add-view-in-a-hybrid-mvc-webforms-asp-net-application)?

Comment: @namesv: Thanks for asking and yes I did convert my WebForms project to MVC. I've added a note at the beginning of my question related to this fact. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wish to separate the MVC stuff from the rest of the application you might want to put it in a separate `Area`.
You'd have the context menu and separation from the existing mess.

Comment: That's actually not a bad idea.

Comment: **Accepting**: I actually used this without creating custom view engine just to override view paths. I did end up with an additional folder so instead of having `Mvc` and have everything inside it I have `Areas\Mvc` which isn't too bad if I consider that an additional abstraction has been removed.