# Visual studio missing user interface bits

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, orchardcms

I used orchard's codegen to make a boilderplate module.
This created a csproj with boilerplate files and folders in MVC3 format.

However visual studio doesnt have the UI helpers that come along with an MVC project (such as add controller).

How do i change the project settings to get the nice MVC UI back?

Normal MVC project:
[image: Normal MVC project]

Orchards boilerplate project:
[image: Orchards boilerplate project]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4610008/828859

Needed to change this line in the csproj file

```
<ProjectTypeGuids>{E53F8FEA-EAE0-44A6-8774-FFD645390401};{349c5851-65df-11da-9384-00065b846f21};{fae04ec0-301f-11d3-bf4b-00c04f79efbc}</ProjectTypeGuids>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a FAQ. The projects are not set to MVC so that the solution can be open and work even if MVC is not installed on the box. This is to remove a prerequisite. You can get the additional tooling by editing the csproj files and adding the project type. Look at an MVC project to find differences.

Comment: I can't find any info in the FAQ, also went through the .csproj file and compared it to another one, I'm not particularly sure what to look for, can you point me in the right direction?

Comment: I think I just did. Look for <ProjectTypeGuids> in the project files. You'll see a difference between an MVC project and an Orchard module.

Comment: Thanks, found it before and placed an answer above. Thanks for your help