# Orchard module doesn't work when built with VS2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012, orchardcms

I've made a hello world module for orchard following this tutorial http://docs.orchardproject.net/Documentation/Building-a-hello-world-module

I've opened up the csproj in VS2012 and changed the projecttype guids to be MVC https://stackoverflow.com/a/12811015/828859

When I build the module in MVC orchard uses the published DLL.
When i attempt to go to the /helloworld route i get `404 resource cannot be found`

When i save a file and let the dynamic compilation in orchard do it's thing it works fine.

I would like to be able to deploy with a DLL so does anyone have any ideas on the problem?

Comment: Have you checked what's causing the 404? It may be an error that's preventing the tenant from booting up. Check the logs in */AppData/Logs* please. Second thing is how are you working with it in VS - are you opening only the module .csproj or have you added the module .csproj to Orchard.sln? You should add your module to Orchard.sln and work with the whole source if you don't want to go into problems.

Comment: The log files are empty. I'm using Webmatrix 2 and using the open in VS button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, two things.

First - you won't be able to deploy your module as a single DLL. There are lots of things that do not get compiled into the DLL, eg. the Module.txt manifest. It has to be there under `/Modules/<YourModuleName>` (as well as module's `.csproj` file, `.cshtml` files and some more). Otherwise, Orchard won't be able to find your module.

So **the source code for the module has to be there**, although if you build it and the module's DLL is in `/Modules/<YourModuleName>/bin` folder, dynamic compilation won't kick in.

Second - **module development should be done using full source code** - not with the downloaded deployment package. Please read [here](http://docs.orchardproject.net/Documentation/Setting-up-a-source-enlistment) how to get full source code.